# Cannot connect to database The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I am trying to deploy my node backend on heroku but I am facing the error that :-

```
 Cannot connect to database The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

Everything is working fine in the development mode, my mongo atlas database is being connected and all routes are working fine but as I switched to production, heroku cannot connect to my database.
My server code is :-

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const users = require("./routers/users");
const category = require("./routers/category");
const products = require("./routers/product");
const uploadImages = require("./routers/upload");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  fileUpload({
    useTempFiles: true,
  })
);

// connecting to MongoDB
const mongoURL = process.env.MONGO_URL;

mongoose
  .connect(mongoURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DataBase has been connected !"))
  .catch((err) => console.log("Cannot connect to database", err.message));

// routes
app.use("/users", users);
app.use("/category", category);
app.use("/images", uploadImages);
app.use("/products", products);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`I am listening at ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Do you have the `.env` file on your heroku instance ?

Comment: no, I have ignored the env file through .gitignore as I have another repo that is public.

Comment: You will need to make a copy of that file on the server before running the express app. Everything else looks good.

Comment: Check this out from the official Heroku docs:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Yes, I remove the lines that were ignoring the ```.env``` files in ```.gitignore``` and The database connected as Heroku can now read my url string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had added my `.env` file which includes my mongo connection url string, in my `.gitignore` file. Due to this, Heroku wasn't able to read my connection string and the logs were giving the url `undefined`. I just removed the lines in the `.gitignore` that were ignoring the `.env` file and Heroku was able to connect to my mongo atlas database